# Firebase Analytics how to fetch more information

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using in my android app firebase analytics, and it does give me some information.However where Can I check for example operating system usage ( for ex. android os 5.0 10 % , 6.0 20 % etc). Also where can I check device list.And model. I have small part called devices, but when i click on it it doesnt expand or give more information on that.It mainly gives me "other" 75 %.

Answer (score 0):

It's right there on the home screen for Analytics in Firebase console, just scroll down a little[image: Firebase device & os stats]

If you need more detailed information. You can try Fabric's crashlytics which was recently acquired by Google. It will give you more information than Firebase,If you want to stick with Firebase, you can manually add the parameters when the user is logging in.